# Why is a clause introduced by an interrogative pronoun (wo+prep) called "weiterführender Nebensatz"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Can anyone help to understand: why do we call this *weiterführender Nebensatz*?

> Beim Arbeiten werde ich ständig unterbrochen, **worüber ich mich oft ärgere**.

Comment: I for one don't call it that. A reference to who "we" is would improve this question

Comment: @vectory, that's because you didnt't learn DaF in an uni setting ;)

Comment: Please check the input method of your computer. It produces dots above the character following the vowel you want to make an umlaut of.

Comment: @Dan searching for a reference would nevertheless present an opportunity to find an explanation. Sometimes it helps to just ask the question properly. I don't know why Millen can't do that, whereas it's out of the question whether I could pick one out easily to satisfy myself.

Comment: @vectory, my bad. wasn't my best renaming. edited it a bit to make it less general and closer to the original intention of the author.

Answer (score 4):

> Beim Arbeiten werde ich ständig unterbrochen, **worüber** ich mich oft ärgere.

The above example uses a special kind of relative clause introduced by *worüber*. It often **refers to the whole previous clause**. Such clauses are called *weiterführende Nebensätze* because they don't pick an item of the previous clause and explain it further but rather continue (*weiterführen*) the previous thought.

There are other words introducing such clauses as *was*, *weshalb*, *weswegen*, *wovon*, *worin*, *woran*, *wobei*, *wogegen*, etc. – the whole bunch of prepositions prefixed by *wo-*. Note these marker words aren't enough to make a clause a *weiterführender Nebensatz*. You have to check from context if one item is picked from the previous clause and explained or not.

The alternative phrasing with two main clauses is

> Beim Arbeiten werde ich ständig unterbrochen. **Darüber** ärgere ich mich oft.

*Darüber* refers to the whole previous clause again.

Answer (score 2):

Simply speaking, the word order of the antecedent (finite verb in final position) and its use of a relative pronoun ("worüber") marks the clause as a relative clause. It is leading further ("weiterführend") in the sense that it could as well be the next main clause: "Darüber ärgere ich mich oft". It would be rather an introduction if leading with the grammatical subject, "Ich ärgere mich ...", which could be extended variously, e.g. "... über Unterbrechungen bei der Arbeit".

The fact that its written as it is stems from theme and focus structure. The theme, that is passivity, comes in the front, the focus topic (the rheme), the reaction, follows; this reflects how we perceive cause and effect. This Nebensatz is parenthetical. But the embedded context isn't finished and can continue in the next sentence. Hence, it is *weiterführend*.